# Why I cannot find Shared folder in Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app, email-template, content-builder, folder

I want to hide some folder to specific user. And choose to move to Shared Folder and Deny them in permission for specific user. But I cannot find where is the shared folder in my Marketing Cloud.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) You dont have the permissions for it

B) Your Organization has only one Business Unit

C) Maybe your Edition does not include it

D) Salesforce has missconfigured your business unit, ask support they might reconfigure and make the service available

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.
A. I'm admin, therefore, I should have seen it.
B. I will check it.
C. How to know which is my current edition?
4. After checking above, I will consider asking Salesforce for support.